# Can I get a straight edge after separating a face from a beveled shape?

Tags: edit-mode

I added some edges and beveled them to create a more rounded rectangle shape, as you can see in the picture below. Now I also want to put two doors in front of the main shape. So what I did, is duplicate the front face of the rectangle, added a loop cut and then separate both doors. However, now I also have that rounded shape in the middle of my two doors door. But I want the doors to perfectly match together. So I want it to be straight line basically.
Can I get rid of the rounded corners in the middle?

I also tried extruding first, separate and fill the face, but that also give me a weird front face of the door itself, as you can see in the second picture.

**EDIT** I also tried adding an edge loop, which you can see in the third picture. But that still doesn't give me a really sharp edge. I still have a rounded corner, as you can see in the third picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to add support edge loops to keep the edges sharp

Comment: I have tried that as well, I have added a third picture to show that. But I still have those little rounded edges in the middle. I want to get them completely straight.

Comment: See this topology, it worjs: https://zupimages.net/up/23/06/8ep7.gif

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/1L2ybGc) something like what you want? There may be no need for subdivision at all..

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question is a bit misleading, it looks like you have rounded edges not from beveling, but from a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

To make those edges sharp you can select them in *Edit Mode*, go to *Item* > *Edges Data* and set the *Mean Crease* to 1 (or a lower value if you want a slight roundness).

[image: mean crease]

Comment: Ah that's true. I have added a subdivision modifier before adding loop cuts and bevelling those. So I probably should have added those later one, first make the shape.